How can I manipulate the pixels of an image quickly using js?
I want to extract the pixels of an image that match some condition in backend (node.js), manipulation for better ocr with overlapping text of different ink colors.
Something like https://onlinepngtools.com/extract-color-from-png, can process instantly. But my implementation in node.js took about 5 - 6 seconds which is too slow for me. Any ideas to speed up?


// Get the image data
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // target color reference
  const matchColor1 = { R: 100, G: 87, B: 34 };
  const matchColor2 = { R: 32, G: 53, B: 81 };

  // Loop through each pixel and extract the red color
  for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    const R = imageData.data[i];
    const G = imageData.data[i + 1];
    const B = imageData.data[i + 2];

    const color = { R, G, B };

    // Check if the pixel is red (you can adjust the threshold as needed)
    const match = diff(color, matchColor1) < 20 && R <= 120; // yellow label
    const match2 = diff(color, matchColor2) < 28 && R < 120; // white label
    const condition = match || match2;

    if (condition) {
      // Set the pixel to black
      imageData.data[i] = 0; // R component
      imageData.data[i + 1] = 0; // G component
      imageData.data[i + 2] = 0; // B component
      // imageData.data[i + 3] = 255; // Alpha component (optional, uncomment if needed)
    } else {
      // Set the pixel to white
      imageData.data[i] = 255; // R component
      imageData.data[i + 1] = 255; // G component
      imageData.data[i + 2] = 255; // B component
      // imageData.data[i + 3] = 255; // Alpha component (optional, uncomment if needed)
    }
  }

  // Put the modified image data back onto the canvas
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);




Try commenting out single lines or replace them with simple statements in order to detect the bottle neck. You didn't post your diff function. Try replacing it with something like function diff (c1,c2) { return true; } and check if it's faster. Or comment out the last line ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);.
